# Debugging a site that errors on Blackberry... without a blackberry

Tags: blackberry

What's the best way (if there is one) to debug an error on my site reported to affect Blackberry only? Is there an emulator, or better yet, a proxy of some kind?

Comment: BB browsers are very different depending on the OS version. Up to OS 4.7 the browser was very limited. Then they changed again in OS 5.0. And in OS 6.0 they changed again to a WebKit based browser. Once you know the OS version, you could [download a simulator](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like http://crossbrowsertesting.com/. We have used this in the past to test all manner of scenarios to great effect.